# Printing PDF in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, printing, razor-pages

In my quest to learn ASP.NET core I've created a simple CRUD application using asp.net core 3.1. I want to print my Details page as a Invoice. I have looked around and it seems like printing PDF in full .NET Framework was more available.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have come across free libraries like SelectPDF, WKHTMLTOPDF, PDFSharp but quiet frankly the samples are pre- asp.net core and cannot quiet integrate it with ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. Actually, if I'm not mistaken some of the libraries mentioned above are not compatible with Razor Pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have come across free libraries like SelectPDF, WKHTMLTOPDF, PDFSharp but quiet frankly the samples are pre- asp.net core and cannot quiet integrate it with asp.net core Razor Pages.

I suggest that you could use client side library.Because what you metioned are all server side libraries,they all need to find the view and convert to string.As far as I known,it seems no such direct method to convert razor pages to string.So I suggest that you could use `jsPDF` library.

Here is a whole working demo:

```
@page
@model DetailsModel
<div id="details">       //be sure add this id...

    <h1>Details</h1>

    <div>
        <h4>test</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.test.Name)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.test.Name)
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.test.Id">Edit</a> |
        <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">Generate PDF</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function demoFromHTML() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
            // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
            // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
            source = $('#details')[0];

            // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style
            // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
            // There is no support for any other type of selectors
            // (class, of compound) at this time.
            specialElementHandlers = {
                // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                    return true
                }
            };
            margins = {
                top: 80,
                bottom: 60,
                left: 40,
                width: 522
            };
            // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
            // 'inches' in this case
            pdf.fromHTML(
                source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                margins.left, // x coord
                margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

                function (dispose) {
                    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
                    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                    pdf.save('Test.pdf');
                }, margins);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I work for SelectPdf.*

SelectPdf does support ASP.NET Core + Razor Page. Samples are available via download from SelectPdf website.

Sample code here:

```
@page
@model SelectPdf.Samples.Pages.ConvertUrlToPdfModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "SelectPdf Free Html To Pdf Converter for .NET Core - Convert from Url to Pdf - C# / ASP.NET Core MVC6";
    ViewData["Description"] = "SelectPdf Convert from Url to Pdf Sample for C# ASP.NET MVC. Pdf Library for .NET with full sample code in C# and VB.NET.";
    ViewData["Keywords"] = "convert from url to pdf, pdf library, sample code, html to pdf, pdf converter";
}

<form method="post">
    <article class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title">SelectPdf Free Html To Pdf Converter for .NET Core - Convert from Html to Pdf - C# / ASP.NET Core MVC6 Sample</h1>
        </header>
        <!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            <p>
                This sample shows how to use SelectPdf html to pdf converter to convert an url to pdf, also setting a few properties.
            </p>
            <p>
                Url:<br />
                <input type="text" style="width: 90%;" value="https://selectpdf.com" asp-for="TxtUrl" />
            </p>
            <div class="col2">
                Pdf Page Size:<br />
                <select asp-for="DdlPageSize" asp-items="Model.PageSizes"></select>
                <br />
                <br />
                Pdf Page Orientation:<br />
                <select asp-for="DdlPageOrientation" asp-items="Model.PageOrientations"></select><br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                Web Page Width:<br />
                <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" value="1024" asp-for="TxtWidth" /> px<br />
                <br />
                Web Page Height:<br />
                <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" value="" asp-for="TxtHeight" /> px<br />
                (leave empty to auto detect)<br />
                <br />

            </div>
            <div class="col-clear"></div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="BtnConvert" value="Create PDF" class="mybutton" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- .entry-content -->
    </article>
</form>

// C# code below

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace SelectPdf.Samples.Pages
{
    public class ConvertUrlToPdfModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            DdlPageSize = "A4";
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public string TxtUrl { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string DdlPageSize { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> PageSizes { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "A1", Text = "A1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "A2", Text = "A2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "A3", Text = "A3" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "A4", Text = "A4" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "A5", Text = "A5" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Letter", Text = "Letter" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "HalfLetter", Text = "HalfLetter" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Ledger", Text = "Ledger" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Legal", Text = "Legal" },
        };

        [BindProperty]
        public string DdlPageOrientation { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> PageOrientations { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Portrait", Text = "Portrait" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Landscape", Text = "Landscape" },
        };

        [BindProperty]
        public string TxtWidth { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string TxtHeight { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            // read parameters from the webpage
            PdfPageSize pageSize =
                (PdfPageSize)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfPageSize), DdlPageSize, true);

            PdfPageOrientation pdfOrientation =
                (PdfPageOrientation)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfPageOrientation),
                DdlPageOrientation, true);

            int webPageWidth = 1024;
            try
            {
                webPageWidth = System.Convert.ToInt32(TxtWidth);
            }
            catch { }

            int webPageHeight = 0;
            try
            {
                webPageHeight = System.Convert.ToInt32(TxtHeight);
            }
            catch { }

            // instantiate a html to pdf converter object
            HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

            // set converter options
            converter.Options.PdfPageSize = pageSize;
            converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = pdfOrientation;
            converter.Options.WebPageWidth = webPageWidth;
            converter.Options.WebPageHeight = webPageHeight;

            // create a new pdf document converting an url
            PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(TxtUrl);

            // save pdf document
            byte[] pdf = doc.Save();

            // close pdf document
            doc.Close();

            // return resulted pdf document
            FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
            fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Document.pdf";
            return fileResult;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the link to this ASP.net Core sample?

Comment: https://selectpdf.com/download/SelectPdf-Samples-v20.2.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with Syncfusion, they have a great library.

https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net-core/pdf-library