# Convert razor page to PDF

Tags: c#

Is there another way/code to convert a razor page to pdf? I tried including ironpdf and itexsharp but I keep on getting errors. I've been trying to resolve the errors but it only leads to the application being unresponsive. I'm stucked in this task. Please help me, thanks.

Here is the cshtml of the razor page i want to convert in pdf file.

```
@page
@model TestApp01.Pages.Clients.PrintModel
@{
}

<br>
<h2>Edit Client</h2>

@if (Model.errorMessage.Length > 0)
{
    <div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
        <strong>@Model.errorMessage</strong>
        <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
    </div>
}

<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.clientInfo.id"/>
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Policy Number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="policy_number" value="@Model.clientInfo.policy_number" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="@Model.clientInfo.first_name" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="@Model.clientInfo.last_name" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="@Model.clientInfo.email" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Phone:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="@Model.clientInfo.phone" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="@Model.clientInfo.address" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-3 d-grid">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" href="/Clients/Index">Submit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 d-grid">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/Clients/Index" role="button">Cancel</a>
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

And here its cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SmtpServer.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using NuGet.Protocol.Plugins;
using System.Net;


namespace TestApp01.Pages.Clients
{
    public class PrintModel : PageModel
    {
        public ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
        public String errorMessage = "";
        public String successMessage = "";
        public void OnGet()
        {
            String id = Request.Query["id"];
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "myDB";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=@id";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                clientInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                                clientInfo.policy_number = reader.GetString(1);
                                clientInfo.first_name = reader.GetString(2);
                                clientInfo.last_name = reader.GetString(3);
                                clientInfo.email = reader.GetString(4);
                                clientInfo.phone = reader.GetString(5);
                                clientInfo.address = reader.GetString(6);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            clientInfo.id = Request.Form["id"];
            clientInfo.policy_number = Request.Form["policy_number"];
            clientInfo.first_name = Request.Form["first_name"];
            clientInfo.last_name = Request.Form["last_name"];
            clientInfo.email = Request.Form["email"];
            clientInfo.phone = Request.Form["phone"];
            clientInfo.address = Request.Form["address"];

            if (clientInfo.policy_number.Length == 0 || clientInfo.first_name.Length == 0 ||
                clientInfo.last_name.Length == 0 || clientInfo.email.Length == 0 ||
                clientInfo.phone.Length == 0 || clientInfo.address.Length == 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "All the fields are required";
                return;
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: one simple way. end of the day, the razor page is rendered as HTML, you can use the javascript library to make this conversion. any way check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876743/printing-pdf-in-asp-net-core-3-1-razor-pages